# Display 2 columns in listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have 2 columns meal and serving, and wanted to display it in listview.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    private ListView lv;
//private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.meal_result);
BreakFastLog info = new BreakFastLog(this);
info.open();

String data1 = info.getMealNameData();
String data2 = info.getServingData();

String[] inputData = data1.split( " " );
String[] inputData2 = data2.split( " " );

lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvBF);   

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String[]>> mylistData =
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String[]>>();

int[] columnIds = new int[] {
        R.id.tvBreakfastMealContainer, R.id.tvBreakfastServingContainer};

HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
//initialize row data

map.put( "Meal", inputData );
map.put( "Serving", inputData2 );
mylistData.add( map );

//lv.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inputData ) );

SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter =
           new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.breakfast_listview_header,
                   new String[] {"Meal", "Serving"}, columnIds);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

lv.setTextFilterEnabled( true ); 

info.close();
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

       String[] data_meal;
       String[] data_serving;

 MyCustomAdapter()
 {
       data_meal = null;
       data_serving = null;
 }

 MyCustomAdapter( String[] meal, String[] serving )
 {
       data_meal = meal;
       data_serving = serving;
 }

 public int getCount()
 {
       return data_meal.length;
 }

 public String getItem( int position )
 {
       return null;
 }

 public long getItemId( int position )
 {
       return position;
 }

 public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
 {

       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       View row;

       row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.breakfast_listview_header, parent, false );

       TextView txtMeal = ( TextView ) row.findViewById ( R.id.tvBreakfastMealContainer );
       TextView txtServing = ( TextView ) row.findViewById ( R.id.tvBreakfastServingContainer );

       txtMeal.setText( data_meal[ position ] );
       txtServing.setText( data_serving[ position ] );

       return (row);

     }
 }
```

EDIT: XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst" >

<!--  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBreakfastDateContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" /> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBreakfastMealContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBreakfastServingContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

But they are just displaying only in one row? Help me figure out how to display those records individually. Thanks.

Comment: For multiple columns you can use `GridView`

Comment: But I'd like to do it in Listview

Comment: Then use custom adapter for `ListView` and use a custom layout for each row where you can make two columns in each row.

Comment: I added my customadapter, but it's not displaying what I wanted to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing right but there is one more thing to do in your `getView()` code. Make your `row` layout into a `row` with two `columns` and fill both the `columns` simultaneously in the `getView()` function. That will make your `ListView` a two column list.

Comment: how do I insert two columns? Sorry I'm new to Android dev.

Comment: oOh just paste your XML for row then i will modify it to look like a two column row :)

Comment: I added my breakfast_listview_header layout in my post above.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use GridView instead of ListView?